# Regex excluding string

Tags: php, regex, pcre

I am using the following PCRE to match URLS with preg_match() in PHP:

```
~(?i)\b((?:[a-z][\w-]+:(?:/{1,3}|[a-z0-9%])|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:\'".,<>?«»“”‘’]))~
```

I'm trying to exclude .onion sites from being matched. I've noticed some similar questions already answered on this site but unfortunately wasn't able to transfer their solutions to my problem.

So far i have tried:

```
~(?i)\b((?:[a-z][\w-]+:(?:/{1,3}|[a-z0-9%])|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:\'".,<>?«»“”‘’]))(?!\.onion)~
```

and:

```
~(?i)\b((?:[a-z][\w-]+:(?:/{1,3}|[a-z0-9%])|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:\'".,<>?«»“”‘’]))(?:(?!\.onion).)~
```

with no luck (both still match http://test.onion ). Would anyone be able to point out why these aren't working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can insert this **negative lookahead** at start of your regex:

```
(?!.*?\.onion)
```

i.e.

```
~(?i)\b(?!.*?\.onion)((?:[a-z][\w-]+:(?:/{1,3}|[a-z0-9%])|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:\'".,<>?«»“”‘’]))~
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a negative lookahead at the start.

```
(?i)(?!.*\.onion(?!\S))\b((?:[a-z][\w-]+:(?:/{1,3}|[a-z0-9%])|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:\'".,<>?«»“”‘’]))
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/tI4hQ7/6)

Note that this regex would match `http://test.onion.foo` but not the links which has  `.onion` at the end.

Comment: Thank you. Had to give the accepted answer to @anubhava though, as you said this solution will still match http://test.onion/foo